# NullPointerException: android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler() on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, fragmentmanager

I am facing following issue.

Scenario:

For the very first time when I signup thru app, I am able to see tabs and there content but when I logout and try to login for the same code for viewpager i get following exception:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Handler
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()'  on a null
>   object reference

but when open navigation menu and select after that I get data and tabs are shown viewpager shows tabs.

Contents:
I have 2 tabs

Below is my code:

```
 public void setupDashboardTabs(List<CreateFragmentsPojo> fragments) {
    this.fragments = fragments;

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    setupDashboardViewPager(fragments);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setUpFontStyleForTabs();
}


public void setupDashboardViewPager(List<CreateFragmentsPojo> fragments) {
    try {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.size(); i++) {
            adapter.addFragment(fragments.get(i).getFragment(), fragments.get(i).getTitle());
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
>   getting nullpointer execption at this line

Code to logout:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
 W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1949)
 W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1965)
 W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
 W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
 W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:513)
 W/System.err:     at io.skreem.dashboard.DashboardActivity.setupDashboardViewPager(DashboardActivity.java:459)
 W/System.err:     at io.skreem.dashboard.DashboardActivity.setupDashboardTabs(DashboardActivity.java:443)
 W/System.err:     at io.skreem.dashboard.DashboardActivity$4.onResponse(DashboardActivity.java:408)
 W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: was not helpful

Comment: any success with fixing this error? I am facing the same problem sometimes

Comment: Yes I have fixed it.

Comment: I did a work around for the same.

Comment: what was the work around?

Answer (score 0):

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

is the problem. As you have 2 tabs. Which means 2 pages but you are forcing 3 as the PageLimit. Also whats the need of adding fragment to adapter?

Comment: hey, Adapter is used to display fragments.   setOffscreenPageLimit(3) for other tabs, that should not be a problem as that works with other

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and it has been caused by the reuse of `ViewPager` instance by different instances of the fragment. There was an exception after `ViewPager.setAdapter()` has been called for the second time. If this is the issue you experience, you can try a solution I used. To solve the issue I had to remove adapter in `onDestroyView()` method of my fragment.

Project demoing the issue and the solution [can be found here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37114342#comment40).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **super.onBackPressed()**
and call **finish()**

```js
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//     super.onBackPressed();
       finish();
}
```

I don't know why but this worked in my case!